# Regular Expression in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, expression, text-mining

I am using regular expression to select a specific pattern between two semicolon ";"

The string that I am testing on is:

```
; DNA catabolic process ; adf sdfc sdfwefsdf ;
```

And I am using the following regex in vim to select the "DNA" pattern and the remaining two words before the semicolon ";" so that the remaining pattern after the semicolon "i.e adf sdfc ..." will not be selected.  I am not able to figure out a way to select the remaining pattern after "DNA" and before the semicolon.  Do you have any idea to solve this?

Here is the regex that I came up with:

```
:%s/\(\;\)\(\s\)\(\DNA\)/\3\4/cg
```

Comment: What the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the below regex to print the string `DNA` plus the following two words.

```
:%s/; \+\(DNA \+[^;]*\) \+;.*/\1/cg
```

Output:

```
DNA catabolic process
```

- `<space>\+` Matches one or more spaces
- `[^;]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `;` zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment you're looking for might be `([^;])*;`, if you're not really concerned whether it's exactly two words. Or `(\s\+\w\+\s\+\w\+\s*);`, if you need it to be two words only.